# upload csv comma delimited into mysql Parse error:

Tags: php

What could be wrong with my code?..Instead I get..Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

here is my sample code pls may you assist me

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" > 
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="upload csv" name"submit"/>
</form>

<?php

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
    or die ("Couldn't connect to server");

    $db = mysql_select_db("demo", $connection)
    or die ("Couldn't select database");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file,"r");
        while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== FALSE)
        $firstname = $fileop[0];
        $lastname = $fileop[1];
        $email = $fileop[2];

        $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (first_name,last_name,email)values('$firstname','$lastname','$email')";
    }

    if($sql)
    {
        echo "Hello from PHP.";
    }
    }

?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra brace in your PHP:

```
if($sql)
{
    echo "Hello from PHP.";
}
} // remove this
```

Also, your sql query is missing a closing parenthesis, and should be:

```
$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (first_name,last_name,email)values('$firstname','$lastname','$email')");
```

The syntax error that you received was due to the sql query issue in particular -- it was expected a closing parenthesis, but found a semicolon instead.

You should also consider moving the `if ($sql)` logic into the `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` block, since it can only occur within that scope anyway. That might also resolve the "undefined variable" issue that you noted in a comment on Shankar's answer.

One more note... it looks like your `while` loop is only looping through the `$firstname = $fileop[0];` line, since you don't have braces around the rest of the logic. Do you intend something like this?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    $processed = false;
    while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $firstname = $fileop[0];
        $lastname = $fileop[1];
        $email = $fileop[2];

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (first_name,last_name,email)values('$firstname','$lastname','$email')");

        $processed = true;
    }

    if($processed)
    {
        echo "CSV was processed.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "CSV was not processed.";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Submission was not found.";
}
```

Comment: the page has gone..white?

Comment: Hard to say -- I've updated my example code with some better debug output. It's often wise to make sure that every possible code path results in visible output clearly noting which path was followed, until you've got it working reliably.

Comment: perfect..the page now loads..now i am uplodin excelcsv but it returns Submission was not found. ...may you solve?

Comment: At this point, your best bet is probably to Google "php post submit is not set" or a variation of the same, and spend some time debugging. Such as asking the question, "is $_POST set at all?" The PHP $_POST docs (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) include a comment with `if (!empty($_POST))`, that would be useful to check. Things like that.

Comment: thanks alot.. i have never chat with a guru.. all this took me 2weeks but you secs am now checking the link..or maybe its the soccerer .r joomla 2.5.11 error..i feel helpless coz cant jus upload csv into the mysql..could you know any software that upload csv into mysql through joomla..

Comment: perfect this works....but when i click upload without csv it takes too long,,,how can i cure that?

Comment: You should probably select an answer to this question in order to wrap it up, then post your new question, in order to get fresh attention. Otherwise you're reducing your audience from "all of StackOverflow" down to pretty much just me, not to mention losing clarity as the question focus drifts. In your new question, I'd advise including your current code, as well as details on how long "too long" is, compared to how long it takes when you do upload a csv, perhaps the timing for both a small csv and a large csv for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra brace here

```
if($sql)

{
    echo "Hello from PHP.";

} // here..... remove it
}
```

and change your mysql_query statement to

```
 $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (first_name,last_name,email)values('$firstname','$lastname','$email')");
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you added the closing parenthesis outside of the string but also removed the closing parenthesis from the "values()" section of the query, which simply shifts the bug.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\csv\plugins\system\sourcerer\helper.php(507) : runtime-created function on line 22

Comment: That could be a scoping issue -- I've updated my answer to suggest a solution for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies here:

```
$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (first_name,last_name,email)values('$firstname','$lastname','$email')";
```

This hasn't been closed off properly. It should look like this ( you missed the closing bracket):

```
$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (first_name,last_name,email)values('$firstname','$lastname','$email')");
```

Comment: For what it's worth, there's also an extra brace in the PHP.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn thanks, I didn't spot that, I just looked at the error he supplied

Comment: thanks i havere placed but i get this Notice: Undefined variable: sql in

Comment: could you debug.Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\csv\plugins\system\sourcerer\helper.php(507) : runtime-created function on line 22